# How to specify Synchronous request in Dajax or Dajaxice?

Tags: ajax, django, jquery, dajaxice, dajax

I need to set the equivalent 'async' setting of jQuery.ajax() in Dajax or Dajaxice requests to avoid continue the script execution before my Dajaxice callback ends.

```
$(".some_selector").click(
    Dajaxice.apps.forum.forum_com(my_js_callback, {'id':$(this).attr("id")});
    // More js code here.. Here should not continue before call ends.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i think this is not possible yet.
To workaround this lack i put my code inside "my_js_callback" funcion.